# Wireshark or MC installation wants to remove gnome and more

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt

I want to install wireshark or mc (Midnight Commander) with `apt-get` or `synaptic`, but I get a message that "this installation will remove a lot of actually installed packages".
There are for example `gdebi`, `gedit`, `gnome`, `vino`, etc. I don't understand. Of course I need these packages.

Transcript of `apt-get install mc`:

```
apt-get install mc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree            
Retrieving state information ... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer needed:
  aptdaemon cheese-common empathy-common evolution-common gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-tracker-0.16 gnome-panel-data gnome-session-common gnome-themes-standard-data
  gstreamer1.0-nice gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libavcodec54 libavformat54 libcamel-1.2-43 libcaribou-common
  libchromaprint0 libcrack2 libebackend-1.2-6 libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-17
  libedata-cal-1.2-20 libedataserver-1.2-17 libelf1 libfluidsynth1 libgcr-base-3-1 libgexiv2-2 libgoa-1.0-common libgrilo-0.2-1
  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libibus-1.0-5 libimobiledevice4 libmpg123-0 libmx-common libnm-gtk-common libopencv-core2.4
  libopencv-flann2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpwquality-common libpwquality1
  libraw9 libsbc1 libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsrtp0 libsystemd-journal0 libtbb2 libusbmuxd2 libwebp4 libx264-133 libytnef0
  metacity-common python-aptdaemon python-defer python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-dbus python3-defer python3-gi python3-pkg-resources
  python3-software-properties
To remove them, use the "apt-get autoremove".
Install the following extra packages:
  accountsservice aptdaemon cheese-common colord empathy-common evince-common evolution-common evolution-data-server-common folks-common
  gdebi-core gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-tracker-0.16 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-control-center-data gnome-menus gnome-packagekit-data gnome-panel-data gnome-session-common
  gnome-themes-standard-data gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
  init-system-helpers libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12 libarchive13 libasn1-8-heimdal libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data
  libatspi2.0-0 libavcodec54 libavformat54 libavutil52 libcairo2 libcamel-1.2-43 libcaribou-common libcolord1 libcolorhug1 libcrack2
  libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libebackend-1.2-6 libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0
  libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-17 libedata-cal-1.2-20 libedataserver-1.2-17 libegl1-mesa libelfg0 libflac8 libfolks-telepathy25
  libfolks25 libgbm1 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgee-0.8-2 libgeocode-glib0 libgexiv2-2
  libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnomekbd-common libgoa-1.0-common libgrilo-0.2-1 libgsf-1-114
  libgsf-1-common libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-common libgweather-common
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libibus-1.0-5 libicu52
  libimobiledevice4 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libkrb5-26-heimdal libldb1 libllvm3.3 libmx-common libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-util2
  libntdb1 libopus0 liborc-0.4-0 libpackagekit-glib2-16 libpixman-1-0 libproxy1 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libraw9
  libroken18-heimdal libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsmbclient libsoundtouch0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libswscale2
  libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-journal0 libsystemd-login0 libtasn1-3 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger3 libtevent0 libtiff5
  libtracker-extract-0.16-0 libtracker-miner-0.16-0 libtracker-sparql-0.16-0 libudev1 libusbmuxd2 libva1 libvpx1 libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwebp4 libwind0-heimdal libx11-6 libx264-133 libxcb-xfixes0
  libxi6 libxml2 libytnef0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 mc-data metacity-common nautilus-data python-aptdaemon python-gi python-gi-cairo
  python-talloc python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-dbus python3-defer python3-gi python3-pkg-resources python3-software-properties
  samba-libs tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils
Navrhované balíky:
  lrzip cups-common rng-tools grilo-plugins-0.2 gstreamer-codec-install gnome-codec-install gstreamer1.0-tools opus-tools arj catdvi
  texlive-binaries dbview djvulibre-bin genisoimage gv odt2txt poppler-utils python-boto python-tz python3-apt-dbg python-apt-doc
  python-dbus-doc python3-dbus-dbg python3-setuptools
Odporúčané balíky:
  lintian gstreamer1.0-x cracklib-runtime libegl1-mesa-drivers
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  aisleriot alacarte baobab brasero caribou caribou-antler cheese dconf-tools empathy eog evince evolution evolution-data-server
  evolution-plugins evolution-webcal file-roller gcalctool gcr gdebi gdm3 gedit gedit-plugins gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  gir1.2-clutter-gst-1.0 gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
  gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gkbd-capplet glchess glines gnect gnibbles gnobots2 gnome
  gnome-applets gnome-bluetooth gnome-color-manager gnome-contacts gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-dictionary gnome-disk-utility
  gnome-documents gnome-font-viewer gnome-games gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-extras gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring
  gnome-media gnome-nettool gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-packagekit gnome-panel gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver
  gnome-screenshot gnome-session gnome-session-bin gnome-session-fallback gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions
  gnome-sudoku gnome-sushi gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-themes-standard gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-guide
  gnome-user-share gnomine gnotravex gnotski gtali gucharmap iagno libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libbrasero-media3-1 libcanberra-gtk3-0
  libcanberra-gtk3-module libcaribou-gtk3-module libcaribou0 libchamplain-0.12-0 libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libcheese-gtk21 libcheese3
  libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-0 libclutter-imcontext-0.1-bin
  libcluttergesture-0.0.2-0 libedata-book-1.2-13 libedataserverui-3.0-1 libepc-ui-1.0-3 libevdocument3-4 libevolution libevview3-3
  libfolks-eds25 libgail-3-0 libgcr-3-1 libgdict-1.0-6 libgdu-gtk0 libgnome-bluetooth10 libgnome-desktop-3-2 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnomekbd7 libgoa-1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-0 libgtkhtml-4.0-common libgtkhtml-editor-4.0-0
  libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgweather-3-0 libmetacity-private0a libmutter0 libmx-1.0-2
  libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libpanel-applet-4-0 libpeas-1.0-0 librhythmbox-core6 libseed-gtk3-0 libtotem0 libunique-3.0-0
  libvte-2.90-9 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwnck-3-0 libyelp0 lightsoff mahjongg metacity mousetweaks nautilus nautilus-sendto
  nautilus-sendto-empathy network-manager-gnome notification-daemon policykit-1-gnome python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets quadrapassel rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugins rygel-preferences seahorse shotwell simple-scan software-properties-gtk sound-juicer
  swell-foop task-gnome-desktop totem totem-plugins tracker-gui transmission-gtk vinagre vino xdg-user-dirs-gtk yelp zenity
Install the following NEW packages:
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-0.16 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio init-system-helpers libarchive13 libasn1-8-heimdal libavcodec54 libavformat54 libavutil52 libcamel-1.2-43
  libcolorhug1 libcrack2 libcupsfilters1 libebackend-1.2-6 libebook-1.2-14 libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-17
  libedata-cal-1.2-20 libedataserver-1.2-17 libegl1-mesa libelfg0 libgbm1 libgcr-base-3-1 libgee-0.8-2 libgexiv2-2 libgrilo-0.2-1
  libgssapi3-heimdal libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libhcrypto4-heimdal libhdb9-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libibus-1.0-5 libicu52 libimobiledevice4 libkrb5-26-heimdal libldb1 libllvm3.3 libntdb1
  libpackagekit-glib2-16 libproxy1 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libraw9 libroken18-heimdal libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common
  libsystemd-journal0 libtelepathy-logger3 libtevent0 libtiff5 libtracker-extract-0.16-0 libtracker-miner-0.16-0 libtracker-sparql-0.16-0
  libudev1 libusbmuxd2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-server0 libwebp4 libwind0-heimdal libx264-133 libxcb-xfixes0 libytnef0
  libzeitgeist-1.0-1 mc mc-data python-talloc python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-dbus python3-defer python3-gi python3-pkg-resources
  python3-software-properties samba-libs
Nasledovné balíky sa aktualizujú:
  accountsservice aptdaemon cheese-common colord empathy-common evince-common evolution-common evolution-data-server-common folks-common
  gdebi-core gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2
  glib-networking glib-networking-common glib-networking-services gnome-control-center-data gnome-menus gnome-packagekit-data
  gnome-panel-data gnome-session-common gnome-themes-standard-data gsettings-desktop-schemas libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.5
  libapt-pkg4.12 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatspi2.0-0 libcairo2 libcaribou-common libcolord1 libcups2 libcupsimage2 libdjvulibre-text
  libdjvulibre21 libflac8 libfolks-telepathy25 libfolks25 libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgeocode-glib0
  libgirepository-1.0-1 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnomekbd-common libgoa-1.0-common libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common
  libgtk-3-common libgweather-common libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libmx-common libnm-glib4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-util2 libopus0
  liborc-0.4-0 libpixman-1-0 libsmbclient libsoundtouch0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libswscale2 libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-login0
  libtasn1-3 libtelepathy-glib0 libva1 libvpx1 libwacom-common libwacom2 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libx11-6 libxi6 libxml2
  metacity-common nautilus-data python-aptdaemon python-gi python-gi-cairo tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs tracker-utils
91 upgraded, 82 newly installed, 183 to remove and 919 not upgraded.
You need to download 118 megabytes of archives.
After this operation, the disk space 235 megabytes
Do you want to continue [Y / n]?
```

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is empty):

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.2.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20131012-14:04]/ wheezy main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.2.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20131012-14:04]/ wheezy main

deb http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian raring contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian quantal contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid contrib non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian squeeze contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian experimental main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main
```

Output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-sk
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=jessie,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main Translation-en
   1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ experimental/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=experimental,n=experimental,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=squeeze,l=Oracle Corporation,c=non-free
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ squeeze/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=squeeze,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=wheezy,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ lucid/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=lucid,l=Oracle Corporation,c=non-free
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ lucid/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=lucid,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ precise/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=precise,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ quantal/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=quantal,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ raring/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=raring,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/ saucy/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=saucy,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=wheezy-updates,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-sk
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/contrib Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=7.3,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=7.3,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=contrib
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.sk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=7.3,o=Debian,a=stable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.sk.debian.org
```

I have used Debian 7 Wheezy - 3.2.0-4-amd64 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Have you any solution for non-conflicting installation?

Comment: Maybe some people know the exact issue and already know the proceeding, but if not, you could paste `apt-get install` outputs.

Comment: Yep, we'll need output from the apt-get install command.  Also, may be worth pasting the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and anything in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: You have probably mixed packages from different Debian releases (stable, testing, experimental) which can generate such problems. Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy`, please?

Comment: @jofel Thanks. I added this output. And yes I had to add packages from different Debian releases because I need special versions of packages sometime. But if I want install package from unstable release I use apt-get -t experimental install name_of_package...

Comment: Your system seems to be mixing experimental and testing. Did you run `apt-get update` first? Is your system up-to-date (`apt-get dist-upgrade`)?

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. I am sorry for my late answer. I tried apt-get update, but it does not help me. I have tha same problem still. Any other idea please?

Answer (score 0):

i suspect this has nothing to do with your installing `mc` - i'm guessing it would show this message for any program you want to install through `apt`. whatever you do **do not** take its advice and run autoremove.

if you want to keep all the listed packages installed then copy the list that `apt` is saying it wants to remove and tell `apt` to install those packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptdaemon cheese-common empathy-common etc
```

do a few packages at a time and see if the list of recommendations get smaller each time - it should.